# <div> being replaced by <p> tags in redactor rich text editor

Tags: redactor

I have read previous questions and answers about the redactor rich text editor but in this version of Craft i only found simple.json and standard.json under **craft/config/redactor**. I have tried with both but `<div>` tags are still replaced by `<p>`. Is there another way to add `<div>` into a redactor rich text field?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new redactor config under craft/config/redactor named Simple-With-Divs.json with the following code:

```
{
    buttons: ['bold', 'italic'],
    toolbarFixed: true,
    replaceDivs: false
}
```

Now you can select Simple With Divs under the Rich Text field type.

Comment: If you found this answer acceptable, please consider approving it ;D

Answer (score 2):

Adding `"replaceDivs": false` to the config file should prevent this.

When I add a div in code view and save the entry, the div is still there when I open the entry again. Once I remove this setting the div is gone once I re-open the entry.